# How to resolve 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200' using ElasticSearch with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, elasticsearch, google-cloud-functions

I know that this question has been asked several times, but the solutions didn't apply to my situation. I have started `ElasticSearch`, `Kibana` using these 2 commands:

```
bin/elasticsearch
bin/kibana
```

And the server is running well, when using browser to go to `http://localhost:9200`, I get the following result:

```
{
    "name" : "vg7RnLh",
    "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
    "cluster_uuid" : "gqDf0H67TxGZGYigAlu2mQ",
    "version" : {
        "number" : "6.1.2",
        "build_hash" : "5b1fea5",
        "build_date" : "2018-01-10T02:35:59.208Z",
        "build_snapshot" : false,
        "lucene_version" : "7.1.0",
        "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
        "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
    },
    "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

And when using `kibana`, everything works fine. Here is the firebase cloud function I wrote, if there's anything wrong, I think it's here:

```
exports.downloadUserInfo = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const { uid } = req.query;

    const searchConfig = {
        uri: 'http://localhost:9200/users/user/' + uid,
        method: 'GET'
    };

    request(searchConfig)
        .then((result) => {
           console.log(result);
           return res.status(200).send(result);
       })
           .catch((error) => {
               console.log(error);
               return res.status(400).send(error);
           });
});
```

Where `request` is a module install by `yarn add request request-promise`. Then, when using `Postman` to test my API, I get this error:

[image]

How do I resolve this?

**Update**

I am also running `flashlight` using command `node app.js`. When inserting a new user to the database, the new user is automatically inserted to the ElasticSearch server too (localhost), however, when I try to read, it throws request error

**Second Update**

This is the API that creates a user:

```
exports.register = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const { firstName, lastName } = req.body;

    admin.database().ref('users').push({ firstName, lastName })
        .then(() => res.status(201).send())
        .catch(() => res.status(400).send());
});
```

When a new user is created by this API, this user is automatically inserted to my localhost ElasticSearch server, because I am using `flashlight` plugin. I don't understand why when I try to read from the same server, there's request error.

Comment: Are you running this code fully deployed to Cloud Functions using `firebase deploy`?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, deployment was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer. As [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) and [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson) pointed out, no matter what, I cannot perform any request from a deployed firebase function to a localhost server.

But with a little help of `flashlight` plugin, I can let my localhost server know that I want to perform a search action now. What I do is that in `config.js` file inside `flashlight` folder:

```
exports.FB_REQ = 'search/request';
exports.FB_RES = 'search/response';
```

What these 2 lines do is to tell my database to create a table called `search` in the database, and the table has 2 subtables, one is called `request` and the other `response`. `flashlight` will monitor your firebase database and update any data in ES server, EXCEPT FOR things you write into `search/request` table. When you write into this table, `flashlight` detects it, and it knows that you would like to perform a search operation right now, and it will run the query you put there on your ES server, and then store the result in `search/response` table, you'll just have to listen to the updates in that table, and that will be your search result.

The new `downloadUserInfo` API should be something like this:

```
exports.downloadUserInfo = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const { uid } = req.query;

    const key = admin.database().ref('search/request')
        .push({ index: 'users', type: 'user', q: uid }).key;

    admin.database().ref(`search/response/${key}`).once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
            return res.status(200).send(snapshot.val());
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return res.status(400).send(error);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is trying to access the local host:

```
uri: 'http://localhost:9200/users/user/' + uid,
```

This won't work: you can't just access "random" ports on the container where your Cloud Functions run.

My guess is that you have ElasticSearch running on your local machine, and that's what `localhost` is meant to refer to. But to run the code in the Cloud Functions environment, you'll need to have ElasticSearch running on a system that is publicly accessible, and specify the IP of that machine in the `uri`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that I was also running `flashlight` plugin, the question is updated

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what flashlight is or how it relates to your issue.  All I can really tell you is that it never makes sense to make a request to localhost from a deployed Cloud Function.

Comment: You can't run arbitrary Node.js programs (such as ElasticSearch) on Cloud Functions. You'll need to provide your own Node.js server for that and wire up the IP address of that server in the `uri`.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions run on a server that Google controls.  They don't run on your machine (except when you're using local emulation for testing).

Your function is accessing a URL at "localhost":

```
const searchConfig = {
    uri: 'http://localhost:9200/users/user/' + uid,
    method: 'GET'
};

request(searchConfig).then(...)
```

In nearly every context, localhost means IP address 127.0.0.1 - the same machine where the code is running.  When your code is running in Cloud Functions, that means localhost is the Google server instance running your code.  This is most certainly not what you want, and unfortunately, you won't be able to access services running on your personal machine, either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that I was also running `flashlight` plugin, the question is updated